# Woocommerce variations products - show price after selecting first attribute

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, e-commerce

I have variable products, which have two attributes: size, and color.
Price is changing only depending on size, color on each size won't change the price at all.

So f.e if I select "XL", it doesn't matter which color will I choose, price wont change at all.

Currently to see the price of a product, user have to select both: size, and color, which is actually reasonable, but I would like to allow user to see the price, after just selecting Size attribute.

How can I achieve it?
thanks

Comment: I don't think I understand ¿are you using the attributes as variations and each variations has his own price? Do you have an example or a site where we can see the problem?

Comment: Yes, so I have attributes: color and size, and then I use them in variations, so I have variations like: L -red L-blue L-black, XL-red, XL-blue etc. 

Or I can also set variations like : [any color] XL, [any color] L etc, but I still have to select both color and size to see the price

I don't have anything live yet, I'm in early stage with this project

Comment: What have you tried so far?